# Iterating through map objects in sass

Tags: css, sass

I was playing a little with scss and ran into this issue which I do understand the cause of, but not the reason for. So I created a nested `$map` and created a `@mixin` in which I use the `@for` rule. As the second `<expression>` I want the `@mixin` to take the length of the desired `$list` which again it does, BUT if I try to compile it will return an **error** saying *"2" is not an integer.* So the `<expression>` is taken, but wrong? According to my knowledge and research it is supposed to be correct. Does anybody have a clue?

[My Codepen example](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/abdXMmG)

```css
$map: (
  'display': (
    'block',
    'flex',
  ),
);

@mixin loop {
  @for $i from 1 through #{length(map-get($map, display))} {
    display: #{nth($i)};  
  }
}

@include loop;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature `#{}` is essentially the `.toString()` of `sass`.

Does it give an error if you omit it?

Comment: @not-a-robot you cant until 10min have passed

Comment: oops, didn't know that :P